# Combining boolean masks, why is in Python: [False, True] and [True, False] == [True, False]

Tags: python

I was busy with combining masks and it strikes me that:

```
>>> [False, True] and [True, False]
[True, False]
```

and

```
>>> [True, False] and [False, True]
[False, True]
```

Why is this the case? Why shouldn't I expect it to be `[False, False]` in both cases?

I also think this is why [`np.logical_and()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) exists in Numpy:

> ```
> >> np.logical_and([True, False], [False, False])
> array([False, False])
> ```

Comment: You are not comparing what you think you are comparing. `bool([False, True])` is `True` and `bool([True, False])` is also `True`.

Comment: The operands of ``and`` are the lists, not the booleans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same reason why:

```
>>> (1,2) and (3,4)
(3, 4)
```

You need to understand that this is not doing element-wise comparison as opposed to `np.logical_and`.

The way `and` works is, if you have `a and b`, it checks whether `a` is `False`, if yes, return `a` else return `b`, does not matter what the value of `b` is.

In your case `[False, True]` is not `False`:

```
>>> bool([False, True])
True
```

Because it is a non-empty list, even `[False, False]` is `True`.
So in the case of `[False, True] and [True, False]`, it checks to see whether `[False, True]` is `False`, which it is not, so it returns the second value. Same for the other case.

A python implementation of the `and` `or` logic would be:

```
def AND(first, second):
    if bool(first) == True:
        return second
    else:
        return first


def OR(first, second):
    if bool(first) == True:
        return first
    else:
        return second
```